# ProgressBar not centered on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I have a recyclerview inside a fragment and I want to show progressBar before data will be populated. ProgressBar is being displayed on the centerTop near the actionBar and not in the middle of the screen. Below is my layout xml for the recyclerview and progressbar. I want the progressbar to be shown centered in the middle of the screen.

recyclerview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/recyclerview" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I'm getting

[image: Image Output]

Comment: Try using `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for the `RecyclerView`

Comment: @A.A. it's still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code instead. I have tested this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem a while ago you might also try listing 
the progress bar before you list the `Recyclerview`

If you leave it how you asked try adding `android:layout_below="@id/recyclerview"`